# Build search functionality in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, parameter-passing, state, zustand

I want to integrate a search functionality in my Next.js app which should look like this:

- User types a keyword in searchBar which is inside of Header
- After clicking on the search button the keyword should be passed on the SearchResult page, in which I load it dynamically into the youtube-search-api link

The structure looks like this:

- Header.js (contains SearchBar component)
- _app.js (contains Header and components)
- SearchResults.js (inside pages folder, should fetch typed keyword from Header)

I tried it with zustand and it looks like this currently:

Header.js:

```
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.header}>
...
      <SearchBar />
...
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

SearchBar.js:

```
import create from 'zustand';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '../styles/Header.module.scss';
import loupe from '../public/images/loupe.png';

const useStore = create((set) => ({
  keyword: '',
  setKeyword: (keyword) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      keyword,
    })),
}));

const SearchBar = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const keyword = useStore((state) => state.keyword);
  const setKeyword = useStore((state) => state.setKeyword);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push('/searchResults');
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.searchBar}>
      <input
        type='text'
        value={keyword}
        placeholder='Suche...'
        onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className={styles.searchBtn} type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>
        <Image src={loupe} alt='' />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

_app.js:

```
import Header from '../components/Header';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
        <Header /> 
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

and SearchResults.js:

```
import { fetchData } from '../lib/utils';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Modal } from 'react-responsive-modal';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube';

export default function SearchResults({ videos }) {
  console.log(videos);

  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null);

  const videoURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + modalData;

  const sortedVids = videos
    .sort((a, b) =>
      Number(
        new Date(b.snippet.videoPublishedAt) -
          Number(new Date(a.snippet.videoPublishedAt))
      )
    )
    .filter((vid) => vid.snippet.title.toLowerCase());

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${styles.playlist_container} ${styles.search}`}>
        <div className={styles.main_container}>
            <h1>Search results</h1>
          {sortedVids
            .filter((v) => v.snippet.title !== 'Private video')
            .map((vid, id) => {
              return (
                <div className={styles.item_container}
                  key={id}>
                  <div className={styles.clip_container}>
                    <Image
                      className={styles.thumbnails}
                      src={vid.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}
                      layout='fill'
                      objectFit='cover'
                      alt={vid.snippet.title}
                    />
                    <button
                      className={styles.playBtn}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setModalData(vid.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
                        console.log(modalData);
                        setModalIsOpen(true);
                      }}
                    >
                      <Image src='/images/play.svg' width='60' height='60' />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className={styles.details_container}>
                    <h3>{vid.snippet.title}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Modal
          open={modalIsOpen}
          onClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}
          center
          classNames={{
            overlay: 'customOverlay',
            modal: 'customModal',
            overlayAnimationIn: 'customEnterOverlayAnimation',
            overlayAnimationOut: 'customLeaveOverlayAnimation',
            modalAnimationIn: 'customEnterModalAnimation',
            modalAnimationOut: 'customLeaveModalAnimation',
          }}
          animationDuration={800}
        >
          <ReactPlayer
            playing={true}
            url={videoURL}
            width='100%'
            height='calc(100vh - 100px)'
            config={{
              youtube: {
                playerVars: {
                  autoplay: 1,
                  controls: 1,
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        </Modal>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const keyword = useStore((state) => state.keyword);

  const { YOUTUBE_KEY } = process.env;
  const uploadsURL = `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCbqKKcML7P4b4BDhaqdh_DA&maxResults=50&key=${YOUTUBE_KEY}&q=${keyword}`;

  async function getData() {
    const uploadsData = fetchData(uploadsURL);

    return {
      videos: await uploadsData,
    };
  }

  const { videos } = await getData();
  return {
    revalidate: 86400,
    props: {
      videos: videos.items,
    },
  };
}
```

Would someone please help me out by telling me what I did wrong and how it works in the right way? Thank you guys!!

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are having?

Comment: @RyanLe Passing 'keyword' into SearchResult doesn`t work

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to access zustand store out of the clientside component.

Comment: I want to use the state global for all components, this was the reason why I took zustand. Sorry, I´m new with nextJs and state management. The goal is to pass the keyword from SearchBar into SearchResult

Comment: @Ydonut13 why do you want to put the keyword in the store? instead you can just pass the keyword in query param and capture that keyword inside the useEffect of searchResult?

Comment: you are using useStore inside getStaticProps, that is outside client side. It won't work

Comment: @Ydonut13 in SearchBar on onClick handler use `history.push(`/searchResults?keyword=${keyword}`)` then on useEffect of searchResult do this `useEffect(()=>{setKeyword(router.query?.keyword ?? "" )},[])`

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar Thanks for your advice!! I need the keyword in getStaticProbs - would you tell me how to get it there ? I tried `const keyword = () => router.query?.keyword ?? '';` but with this I just get an empty array. If I use the useEffect inside of getStaticProbs it throws out an error

Comment: you can't access keyword in getStaticProps as it is only run in build time. you can use getServerSideProps instead

Comment: @Ydonut13 refer [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)